# Populate data step name with today's date in SAS

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I'm brand new to SAS and working from someone else's code as a way of teaching myself, so bear with me if the premise of my question is extremely basic. Also, I've seen a similar question asked elsewhere but not helpful for my particular circumstance given my inexperience with SAS, unfortunately. In any case, here's an overview of what I'm trying to do.

I'm trying to adjust existing code at my workplace to generate a new file every single day, but to append the current day's date to each file so that no files are overwritten and historic data are captured and retained. The following code is what I'm trying to achieve, essentially:

```
Data output_file_[current date];
set input_file;
run;
```

I've also tried to use a macro, like below:

```
%let date = %sysfunc(today(), mmddyyd10.);

Data output_file_&date;
set input_file;
run;
```

These haven't worked, unfortunately. If anybody has alternative thoughts that might be helpful here, please let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you actually use `mmddyyd10.` to format a date value, you'll get something like `11-08-2023`, it is not only a readable date value, but also an invalid part of SAS dataset name.
Strictly, if you don't modify system option `VALIDMEMNAME=`, [3 rules](https://go.documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/v_044/lepg/p1izk3r2g9242gn1gisrik8iebb2.htm#n154mr10gqi475n1kzt06hb7es8v) make an invalid SAS dataset name:

1. The length of the names can be up to 32 characters.
2. Names must begin with a letter from the Latin alphabet (A–Z, a–z) or an underscore. Subsequent characters can be letters from the Latin alphabet, numerals, or underscores.
3. Names cannot contain blanks or special characters except for the underscore.

So `20231108` or `08NOV2023` is OK as a part of a data set name, but `11-08-2023` is not, because the hypens are invalid elements. To use `20231108` or `08NOV2023`, you can use format `yymmddn8.` or `date9.`.

Ex:

```
%let date = %sysfunc(today(), yymmddn8.);

Data output_file_&date;
set input_file;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use dates in either MDY or DMY order for something like this.  Not only will either choice confuse half of the users looking at the resulting values they will not sort in chronological order.  Using YMD order when sticking date strings into names will allow the names to sort properly and avoid having the answer the question: Is that the tenth of December or November twelfth.

You can use the YYMMDDN8. format to generate strings of only digits.

Or you can use YYMMDDD10. format to generate strings with dashes and then convert the dashes into underscores.

Example:

```
1    %let ymd=%sysfunc(date(),yymmddn8.);
2    %put &=ymd;
YMD=20231107
3    %let ymd_dash=%sysfunc(date(),yymmddd10.);
4    %let ymd_underscore=%sysfunc(translate(&ymd_dash,_,-));
5    %put &=ymd_underscore;
YMD_UNDERSCORE=2023_11_07
```

Answer (score 1):

A SAS session has an automatic global macro variable, SYSDATE, that you can use.  The value is a SAS date literal representation *ddmonyy* (i.e. 08NOV23).

The value represents the date when the SAS session started and does **not** roll to the next day at midnight.

Example:

```
data want_&SYSDATE ;
  set sashelp.class ;
run;
```

will log

```
NOTE: There were 19 observations read from the data set SASHELP.CLASS.
NOTE: The data set WORK.WANT_08NOV23 has 19 observations and 5 variables.
```

Comment: All 3 of these were super helpful, thanks to everyone who responded. All of them helped me solve this problem, even though it would only allow me to indicate one correct answer. Onward to my continuing SAS journey!